# Python - couldn't open image

Tags: pygame

IMAGE WITH ERROR IN MY PYTHON GAME:
[image: IMAGE WITH ERROR IN MY PYTHON GAME]

I want to run my application, but see this error, how to fix it?

Image with a correctly format is not a possible to open, this is a simple game make in a Python

```
import random
from livewires  import games
games.init(screen_width=640,screen_height=480,fps=50)
class Ship(games.Sprite):
def update(self):

    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_RIGHT):
        self.angle+=1
    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_LEFT):
        self.angle-=1

    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_1):
        self.angle=0
    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_2):
        self.angle=90
    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_3):
        self.angle=180
    if games.keyboard.is_pressed(games.K_4):
        self.angle=270
class Asteroid(games.Sprite):
    SMALL = 1
    MEDIUM = 2
    LARGE = 3
    images={SMALL : games.load_image("asteroida_s.bmp"),
            MEDIUM : games.load_image('asteroida_m.bmp'),
            LARGE : games.load_image('asteroida_l.bmp')   }
    SPEED=2
def main():
nebula_image=games.load_image("mglawica.jpg")
games.screen.background=nebula_image

for i in range(8):
    x=random.randrange(games.screen.width)
    y=random.randrange(games.screen.height)
    size-random.choice([Asteroid.SMALL,Asteroid.MEDIUM,Asteroid.LARGE,])
    new_asteroid=Asteroid(x=x,y=y,size=size)
    game.screen.add(new_asteroid)
games.screen.mainloop()
def main():
nebula_image=games.load_image("mglawica.jpg",transparent=false)
games.screen.background=nebula_image

ship_image=games.load_image("statek.bmp")
the_ship=Ship(image=ship_image,
    x=games.scren.width/2,
    y=games.scren.height/2)
games.scren.add(the_ship)
games.screen.mainloop()
def play(self):
nebula_image=games.load_image("mglawica.jpg")
games.screen.background=nebula_image
self.advance()
games.screen.mainloop()
def advanced(self):
self.level+=1
BUFFER=150
for i in range(self.level):
    x_min=random.randrage(BUFFER)
    y_min=BUFFER-x_min
    x=self.ship.x+x_distance
    y=self.ship.y+y_distance
    x%=games.screen.width
    y%=games.screen.height
    new_asteroid=Asteroid(game=self,x=x,y=y,size=Asteroid.LARGE)
    game.screen.add(new_asteroid)
def end():
end_message=games.Message(value="Koniec gry",
                          size=90,
                          color=color.red,
                          x=games.screen.width/2,
                          y=games.screen.height/2,
                          lifetime=10*games.scren.fps,after_death=games.screen.quit,
                          is_sollideable=False)
games.scren.add(end_message)
def die(self):
    if self.size !=Asteroid.SMALL:
        for i in range(Asteroid.SMALL):
            new_asteroid=Asteroid(x=self.x,
                                  y=self.y,
                                  size=self.size-1)
            game.screen.add(new_asteroid)
    self.destroy()
```

Comment: Your codes indentation is all off. Indentation is crucial to python. Also I have zero idea what "livewire" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your code is very messy (no indentation), I think I have a way to fix it. First, I question your need to import livewire, and also wonder why you marked this question as pygame. You never imported pygame. So my solution will be written in pygame.

First, you have to load the images (and if you want assign it to a variable):

```
 image = pygame.image.load(filename)
```

Then, you have to convert the Surface, or basically just the image.

```
 image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
```